# C# ObservableCollection get all values where Id is identical

Tags: c#, observablecollection

How could I get all rows, where my Id (it is meant to be like that) is x.

Example list:

```
| Id |  Key  | Value |
----------------------
| 0  | FName | Peter |
| 0  | LName | Griff |
| 0  | Phone | 12345 |
| 1  | FName | Sasha |
| 1  | LName |   Un  |
| 1  | Mail  | SU@m.c|
| 2  | FName | Laura |
...
```

From the list I want to get all 0 and 1... differently to insert them into Sharepoint list.

This data has been inserted to this Collection before and Id is used to keep information for specific person.

All I could come up currently is to use loops, to do that

```
for (int i = 0; i < _dataVm.ADData.Count; i++)
{
    foreach (DataFromAD k in _dataVm.ADData)
    {
        // Not sure, how could I sort out specific data here
    }
}
```

Comment: _dataVm.ADData.GroupBy(x=>x.Id).Where(g=>g.Count() > 1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to group data on `Id` using `groupby` to get seperated items by Id:

```
var result = from d in _dataVm.ADData
             group d by d.Id into g
             select new
                   {
                     Id = g.Key,
                     Data = g.ToList()
                   }
```